# Load RecyclerList Data From One Class To Another Class's RecyclerList

Tags: android, list, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have the `RecyclerList` Using `Sqlite Database`; the Data from `Sqlite` is Showing In the List in `A Class`. What I want to do is; As the Item is Selected From One Class In the List Position Get Load To Another Class.

My Question Is How Is It Possible To Do This. I have Searched A Found An Application On `Play store` Which is Doing the Same Thing I want..

I have `ViewPager` and I want this thing, As the `ListItem` From 1st Class is Selected It should Load to Another Class List... And If comeback and select another It shows again to another class list with the Item Already added...

Comment: On click of an item you can get the id of that item and then pass it to other class. Then load the from sqlite using that id.

Comment: I have done It, I have passes an Item to another class but not in the list, because using the list the app not working

Comment: and the second thing I have databse

Answer (score 1):

you can implement a listener for this. Create an interface which communicates between fragment to fragment or fragment o activity. Ref: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating